# BarChart x-axis labels

Tags: labeling, charts

I am trying to put specific labels on the x-axis of my bar graph. There are 56 bars. I want to have labels 1960, 1970, ... and 2010 on bars 1, 11, ... and 51 respectively with ticks at only those points. I can't seem to be able to figure out how to do this. Code is below. Would anyone be able to help me? Thank you!

```
Show[BarChart[
  data,
  FrameLabel -> {{"A", None}, {"" (*because there are three stacked graphs and only the bottom one has an axis label*), None}},
  ChartStyle -> {{Red}, {EdgeForm[]}},
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 10},
  Frame -> {{True, None}, {True, None}},
  ImageSize -> {3*150, 2*150/3} (*the three graphs are supposed to add up in height to that of another graph*),
  AspectRatio -> 2/9,
  PlotRange -> {0, 
    Max[dataFromTheThreeGraphs] (*so the y-axes are the same*)}]]
```

EDIT: Here's some sample data:

```
data={0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.00437956,0.,0.,0.00236407,0.,0.00510725,0.00300903,0.0030426,0.000983284,0.00102987,0.00304569,0.00285714,0.00100806,0.000982318,0.,0.,0.00188324,0.00172563,0.000807754,0.000795545,0.00233645,0.0015528,0.,0.000776398,0.,0.001321,0.000788644,0.,0.000747943,0.,0.,0.000599161,0.,0.000578704,0.,0.,0.,0.000926355,0.,0.,0.000728597,0.00103448,0.000319898,0.000886001,0.,0.,0.000469373,0.000425532,0.000400882,0.00132475,0.000366569};
dataFromTheThreeGraphs={0.,0.,0.,0.00118064,0.,0.00437956,0.,0.,0.0035461,0.00107875,0.00715015,0.00501505,0.0040568,0.00294985,0.00514933,0.00609137,0.0047619,0.00100806,0.00196464,0.000882613,0.00187793,0.00282486,0.00172563,0.000807754,0.00318218,0.00233645,0.0015528,0.00149365,0.000776398,0.000688705,0.00198151,0.00236593,0.00225904,0.00149589,0.,0.00332889,0.00179748,0.00126743,0.00289352,0.00218103,0.00265675,0.00104275,0.00509495,0.00292887,0.00161616,0.00327869,0.00413793,0.00223928,0.00502067,0.00434075,0.00392465,0.00469373,0.00595745,0.00521147,0.00567752,0.00293255};
```

Comment: Can you provide the `data`?  Or if it's too long, perhaps a short snippet that makes fake data we could use?  First step is usually copying the code and trying to execute it.

Comment: The data are being pulled from a massive excel file. I edited in some sample data. @JasonB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Show[BarChart[data, ChartStyle -> {{Red}, {EdgeForm[]}}, 
  Axes -> False],
 FrameLabel -> {{"A", None}, {"" , None}},
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 10},
 Frame -> {{True, None}, {True, None}},
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
    Automatic}, {{{1, "1960"}, {11, "1970"}, {51, "2010"}}, None}},
 ImageSize -> {3*150, 2*150/3} ,
 AspectRatio -> 2/9,
 PlotRange -> {0, Max[dataFromTheThreeGraphs] }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! Is there a way to reduce/limit the number of labels on the y-axis so there aren't so many crowded in? @JasonB

Comment: Sure, you can manually adjust the ticks, or use `FindDivisions` to help out.  Use the line `FrameTicks -> {{N@FindDivisions[MinMax[data], 4], 
   None}, {{{1, "1960"}, {11, "1970"}, {51, "2010"}}, None}}`

Comment: Apparently Mathematica doesn't recognize MinMax. Where's that from?

Comment: It was introduced in version 10.1.  Replace `MinMax[data]` with `{Min@data,Max@data}`

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I'm sorry, one last question; it's bothering me that the numbers go to different decimal places (i.e., 0.01 and 0.015). Is there a way to normalize that (i.e., make it 0.010 and 0.015)? Would that also be possible for 0?

Comment: Well then you can either work out the excellent [`CustomTicks`](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5599/), or just do them manually:  `FrameTicks -> {{{{0, "0.000"}, {0.002, "0.002"}, {0.004, 
     "0.004"}, {0.006, "0.006"}}, 
   None}, {{{1, "1960"}, {11, "1970"}, {51, "2010"}}, None}}`

Comment: Alrighty, thank you. I would have done so earlier, but I'm not very familiar with the system, so I didn't know if it would block further comments or something. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3769181 Glad I could help!  Often it's nice to use a programmatic way to make the ticks, but when you want a specific configuration like you do, it's often best to just specify them manually.